# Transform Linq Data Structure

Tags: linq, ravendb

I am hoping you can help.

I currently have a data structure like so I got after group by (on name year and state) linq aggregation query (this can not be changed)

```
Name  Year  State  Total

Bobby 2015  East   5

Bobby 2015  West   5

Bobby 2015  North  10

Paul  2015  East   15
```

How can I transform above structure using linq to below structure.

```
Name  Year  East  West  North  Total

Bobby  2015   5      5      10       20

Paul   2015   15     0      0        15
```

Keeping in mind I am trying to avoid using `If` statements like `state=East ? Add east value : 0` in my linq groupby to get desired structure.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you need exactly linq-based solution? If not you may look for specialized c# data aggregation libraries that may calculate pivot table result by your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do a pivot in Linq:

```
var pivot = data
    .GroupBy(d => new {d.Name, d.Year})
    .Select(g => new {
        Name = g.Key.Name,
        Year = g.Key.Year,
        East = g.Where(c => c.State == "East").Sum(c => c.Total),
        West = g.Where(c => c.State == "West").Sum(c => c.Total),
        North = g.Where(c => c.State == "North").Sum(c => c.Total),
        South = g.Where(c => c.State == "South").Sum(c => c.Total),
        Total = g.Sum(c => c.Total),
    });
```

You *can* do more dynamic pivots using `DataTable`s (so you can add columns dynamically) but if your columns are known at design-time this method is cleaner IMHO.

Comment: Thanks @D Standley will give this a go and get back to you.

Comment: If you're attempting to do this inside a RavenDB index you will need to use a map/reduce index and break this apart. Map/reduce is distributed so you can't ever expect to have access to the full results at any time. So make sure your operations are commutative